# como hacer una validación de Login con ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo mi siguiente formulario de Login,estoy trabajando con php,mysql,bootstrap

```html
 <!--CREACION DEL LOGIN-->
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="pwd-container">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <section class="login-form">
              <form method="post" action="validarLogin.php" role="login">
                  <img src="userLogin.ico" alt="img" img-responsive" alt="" />
                   
                   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required class="form-control input-lg"/>
                   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control input-lg" id="password"  required="" />
                   
                   <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Accesar</button>
                  <div>
                    <a href="#">Create account</a> or <a href="#">reset password</a>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </section>  
          </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
```

y mi archivo validarLogin.php

```html
<?php
$usuario=$_POST['email'];
$contraseña=$_POST['password'];

//conectar a la BD
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","administrador","laboratoriodental");
$consulta="SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario' and contraseña='$contraseña'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if($filas>0){
 header("location:Menu.html");
}

else {?>

    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <strong>Error al guardar los datos</strong> 
        <a href="Login.html" class="alert-link">Volver</a>
       </div>  <? } 
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

ya me hace la validación, si corresponde a un nombre que ya tengo en mi BD me manda a otra pagina, y si no, me sale un error, el cual aparece en otra pagina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo quiero que salga en la misma pagina donde esta mi Login,como le puedo hacer?
no se usar ajax

Answer (score 1):

En vez de ejecutar el evento submit, tu botón de enviar debe gatillar un evento en jQuery que a su vez haga un llamado en ajax a tu "validarLogin.php". En vez de tener:

```
<button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Accesar</button>
```

Usar, por ejemplo

```
<button type="button" id="go" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Accesar</button>
```

En combinación con

```
jQuery('#go').on('click',function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
       url:'validarLogin.php',
       type:'POST',
       data: jQuery('#pwd-container form').serialize()
    }).then(function(response) { 
       console.log(response);
    });
});
```

La idea es que a partir de la respuesta obtenida le muestres al usuario si acaso el login falló (luego, se queda donde mismo) o si tuvo éxito (luego se le despliega un mensaje de éxito y se le redirige a menu.html algunos segundos después).

El backend debiera cambiarse para sólo responder con un json diciendo si el login tuvo éxito o no, y quitarle la lógica de manipular la ubicación del usuario.

Comment: Lo mismo se obtiene mediante `$('form').on('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });`.

Comment: y ese codigo de jqueruy, lo pongo en otro archivo? que extension es?

Comment: lo pones entre <script>  y </script>, no me digas que no tienes más código js en todo el sitio

Comment: meto el código en el mismo archivo del Login, entre las etiquetas<script> y </script>, y cambie el tipo del boton,pero al hacer click no me hace nada, le tengo que agregar una linreria o algo?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso necesitas entender como funciona el $.ajax, te lo intentare explicar brevemente con un ejemplo y te dejo la documentación también aquí: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

---

Ahorita tu formulario ya esta trabajando de la forma tradicional, lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar tu pagina a que utilice jQuery. Recuerda que tienes que agregar la librería a tu pagina, aquí el ejemplo de un formulario que manda datos al back con ajax:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Send data to back</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Send data to back example:</h2>
        <hr>
        <form id="myForm">
            <div>
                <label>Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" id="user-name" name="userName" required/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Email: </label>
                <input type="email" id="user-email" name="userEmail" required/>
            </div>
            <button id="send-mail" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>            
</body>

<!-- JS Files at the bottom of the file -->
<!-- import jQuery  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    /* global $, _ */

    $('body').ready(function () {

        /*
            Este .on nos va a server para cachar el evento submit, cuando haces click en un boton del tipo "submit" y quiere enviar el formulario, lo hago de esta forma por si tienes un required en un input o algun type="email" de HTML5 se haga la validacion antes de enviar los datos. De igual forma es buena practica hacer una validacion en el back antes de hacer cualquier cosa.
        */
        $('#myForm').on('submit', function () { // Nos suscribimos al evento "submit" de nuestro formulario el cual se lanzara al hacer click en un boton del tipo submit
            var dataToSend = $(this).serialize(); //Aqui ya tenemos el contexto del formulario por eso usamos $(this)

            // Despues hacemos el $.ajax
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST', // Metodo a utilizar POST, GET, etc...
                url: 'myPage.php', // URL de la pagina que recibira la petición
                data: dataToSend, // Aqui van los datos a enviar, en este caso serializamos los campos del formulario y los asinamos a esta variable por eso solo ponemos esta variable
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data); // Este callback que se lanzara si la url 'myPage.php' responde como un status 200: OK, y lo que imprimas en php lo cachara en la variable data.
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data); // Este callback que se lanzara si la url 'myPage.php' responde con status de error, e.g. 400, 404, 500, etc...
                }
            });

            return false; // Este return es para que no se lanze el evento submit al navegador y no brinque de pagina, si no que se queda esperando la respuesta de nuestra llamada ajax.
        });

    });
</script>
```

Y en el backend lo puedes recibir con el name que tiene el input ya que serializamos todos los campos. Con esta explicación creo que ya puedes utilizar el $.ajax en tu pagina si tienes algún error o duda me dices!

Saludos!